How to set searchbox next to logo picture without big gap in ReactJS
I am trying to set up the details for putting searchbox beside the logo image in order to be in the center of the navbar styled section but for unkown reason the searchob is located in the right corner of the page.
This is the React code
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
            <div className='container-fluid'>
                <div className='row'>
                   <div className='sm2'>
                      <img src={logo} alt=''/>
                   </div>
                   <div className='search-box'>
                      <i><Fas.FaSearch/></i>
                      <input type='text' placeholder='Hit Enter'/>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </header>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home

And this is the css file code where I am facing the issue:
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

header .row {
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
    
}

img{
    width: 20%;
}

.search-box{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

And the result is this one below
Evidence big gap
What should I do to set up the searchob in the middle of the webpag. Any suggestions are acceptable. Thanks a lot

Cause of issue is lies in sm2 & searchbox. By default width: 100% is applied to sm2 and similar thing is happening with search-box .
To fix issue follow below steps :

Add any fixed width to sm2 like width: 100px and also add width: 100% to img so that it covers all available space of sm2.
Same width issue is happening with search-box but to resolve it add display: flex to search-box

Thats all, if you follow this steps it will fixed I have reproduce the issue with html and css only but it will work with react too. Below is working example of html.


header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

header .row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.sm2 {
  width: 100px;
}

.search-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
<header>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='sm2'>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/27590775/pexels-photo-27590775/free-photo-of-a-bird-is-perched-on-a-tree-branch.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt='' />
      </div>
      <div class='search-box'>
        <i><Fas.FaSearch/></i>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Hit Enter' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>



